# https url require index.php in the url. How to fix this?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

we have a magento website www.oursite.in, when i use `http://www.oursite.in/mobiles.html`, it works fine (i.e. index.php isn't required / doesn't appear in the url).

but when I type `https://www.oursite.in/mobiles.html`, it says **404 not found error** `https://www.oursite.in/index.php/mobiles.html` works fine.

how do i rewrite url for https url in .htaccess?

or

is there any other configuration changes in magento?

can somebody throw some light on this for me?

Comment: hello Shathish,Please goto  admin>system>configuration>Web Under secure and secure url change  base urls to https://www.oursite.in/

Comment: @AmitBera: I've already done that.

Answer (score 1):

link below explaining htaccess for https, though it is for codeigniter developer but it will work for magento to..

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/86113/

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1` //this line will hide index.php from url

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1   
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```